# Tool to count stacktraces in a logfile

Tags: java, stack-trace, logfiles, logfile-analysis

Is there a tool that is able to collect and count (Java) stacktraces in a large logfile, such that you get an overview which errors occur most often?

Comment: `grep` / `sed` / `sort` / `uniq`

Comment: @TomaszNurkiewicz : it it even possible to use multiline regular expressions (for stacktraces) with grep? I think not.

Answer (score 3):

I am not aware of any automatic tool but [logmx](http://www.logmx.com/) will give you a nice clean overview of your log file with search options.

Answer (score 1):

This probably isn't the best answer but I am going to try to answer the spirit of your question. You should try [Dynatrace](http://www.dynatrace.com/en/). It's not free and it doesn't work with log files per say but it can get you very detail reports of what types of exceptions are thrown from where and when on top of a lot of other info.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not too sure if there is a tool available to evaluate log files but you may have more success with a tool like [AppDynamics](http://www.appdynamics.com/). This is a monitoring tool which can be used to evaluate Live application performance and can be configured to monitor exception frequency.

Good luck.

Mark.